# What are these kinds of lumps on a tree trunk called?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I saw these lumps on a tree in a park near my house. What are they called?

[image]

Comment: I suspect that there's a specific term for these, as they are all spots where branches were cut off.  "Knot" is probably the closest of the suggestions so far.

Comment: I googled "lumps on the trunk of a tree are called", [see what it said](https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-transsion-infinix-rev1&sxsrf=ALeKk02VqnkOyTqPiDj30RJvrkCHsT35VQ%3A1600266328972&ei=WCBiX6K0OvyZjLsPnuqOoAo&q=lumps+on+the+trunk+of+a+tree+are+called)

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - Which gets you burl, knot, and gall.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Correct

Comment: @KannE You're right.

Answer (score 24):

They are called ***[burls](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/burl)***:

> a roundish warty outgrowth from the trunk, roots or branches of certain trees.

(Collins Dictionary)

Comment: Some are, like the one that looks a little like a pig in the OP's picture, but most of the ;umps in the photo are the remains of branches that have been cut off

Answer (score 19):

At least the more weird-looking ones are called **gnarls**.

> *gnarl*: A knot in wood; a large or hard knot, or a protuberance with twisted grain, on a tree.

[image]

[[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gnarl)]

The word **knot** may be used for a more prosaic protuberance:

> *knot*: a [relatively] small hard area on a tree or piece of wood where a branch was joined to the tree

[image]

[[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/knot)]

Comment: They're all from where the branches have been pruned, I think.  I want to say "stump" but that seems to be mainly when the tree is completely cut down.

Comment: @marcellothearcane all the ones in the picture are knots (or __branch scars__). LUmps on the bark that did not originate from a branch are called [__tumors__ or __burls__ (or UK __burr__) or __gnarls__](https://www.clevelandmetroparks.com/parks/education/blogs/notes-from-the-field/2016/january-2016/burl-blog). I thought they called 'warts' or 'galls' but I couldn't find any online evidence for that.

Comment: @Mitch A gall is a different piece of damage to an oak tree (they may occur on other trees but they are common on oaks). An oak gall or 'oak apple' is caused by a female wasp laying her eggs in the main vein of a leaf. [This website](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/trees/oak/oak-apple-gall-info.htm) will probably tell you more about oak galls than you ever wanted to know!

Comment: @BoldBen hmm.. are you saying a gall is the same as a burl or not? what about tumor? which of these is the same and which not? Oh...just visited the site. A gall is not on the trunk at all. Got it.

Comment: @Mitch Wasn't there a musical, 'Gnarls n' Burls'?

Answer (score 12):

In United Kingdom English these are *burrs*. See a description and definition at
[Woodland Trust](https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/blog/2019/07/burrs-and-bacterial-ooze/):

> You may have noticed trees with a strange knobbly growth or two on
> their trunk. They're easy to spot once you start looking! This
> abnormal growth is called a burr. In American English it’s known as a
> 'burl', so you may find it referred to as both. This growth is a mass
> of shoot and bud tissue that grows manically and forms a distinctive
> growth on the trunk. At its most basic, it's not unlike a benign
> tumour in an animal.

Answer (score 7):

If these are tumors, the more scientific name would be *galls*, although they are sometimes also colloquially referred to as burls.  [*Crown gall*](https://extension.umn.edu/plant-diseases/crown-gall) is a plant disease caused by the bacterium [*Agrobacterium tumefaciens*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrobacterium_tumefaciens) (a.k.a. *Rhizobium radiobacter*).  The tumors are mostly smaller, but if they have been there for a long time, they can grow up to ~30 cm in diameter.  It's a fascinating story: *Agrobacterium* injects a piece of DNA from its plasmid into the plant using a sophisticated transfer mechanism, and through this feat of genetic engineering turns induces a tumor in the plant that serves as an exclusive food factory for the bacterium (the compounds produced by the tumor are encoded in the plamid DNA, and only *Agrobacterium* has the enzymes to break them down and use them as food, so other bacteria or fungi cannot hijack the food source).  There are various bacterial strains that differ in the kinds of tumors they make (some are e.g. only on the roots, others on stems).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other answers, there is also **knur**.  (Seems like sort of halfway between "knot" and "burr".)

> a hard excrescence (as on a tree trunk)

[[Meriam Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knur)

Answer (score 3):

Your photo shows great examples of elongated “**branch collars**” left on the tree when branches were properly removed. The branch collars have grown over the wounds of the original pruning cuts leaving a pronounced bump at each location.

Branch collars are expanded areas at the base of tree branches which are part of the trunk rather than the branch. These expanded areas contain compartmentalizations zones in the wood which function to keep decay from penetrating into the tree. If the branch collars are wounded or removed along with the branch to make a flush cut at the trunk then the tree loses its strongest area of protection and weaker compartmentalizing zones will need to control decay inside the tree.